# Running rust program inside nodejs

Tags: node.js, rust

I've been struggling with this concept:

> You can run rust programs in nodejs.

So we all know rust is fast and can handle concurency well and has static memory management and etc...

So maybe I am dumb to understand this concept. Nodejs is a single thread. And everything is running in a event loop.

So how this is working if we have a program that wrote in rust and has multi proccess involing and etc...

What is the behavior of nodejs if we run the program inside the nodejs?

Comment: Where did this concept come from? Are you sure they didn't simply mean running the Rust program as a subprocess or simulating the execution of a Rust program using NodeJS?

Comment: you can bind rust programs as modules. like module.exports ... this is a functionality rust offers . if you search the rust with nodejs you can see what i mean. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon&ved=2ahUKEwiUu5WcgoXsAhVJ6uAKHXS4B9AQFjAFegQICxAH&usg=AOvVaw3q4R6pcrRdhe_EF9KcZ9sP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJs' addon API (N-API) is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_asynchronous_thread_safe_function_calls). From the section *Asynchronous thread-safe function calls*:

> JavaScript functions can normally only be called from a native addon's main thread. If an addon creates additional threads, then N-API functions that require a `napi_env`, `napi_value`, or `napi_ref` must not be called from those threads.

> When an addon has additional threads and JavaScript functions need to be invoked based on the processing completed by those threads, those threads must communicate with the addon's main thread so that the main thread can invoke the JavaScript function on their behalf. The thread-safe function APIs provide an easy way to do this.

So most calls aren't safe from non-addon-main threads (basically anything affecting the Javascript runtime) though a few calls are dedicated for helping with that.